# Can I disable the mute button on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone

iPhone X has a mute switch on left side. I constantly miss important calls, notifications or meetings, because that switch gets pressed in pocket.

How can I disable it?

Comment: Please note that all iPhone models  have a silence or mute switch.  I have used iPhones for the most part starting with the 3G and kept them in my pockets - from dress pants, to jeans and even my blazer or suit jacket pockets; never have I experienced the button switching accidentally.  However, I’ll concede it is possible for it to happen.  Maybe a case will work for you?

Comment: I am going to try superglue.

Comment: I definable don’t advise that.  When you toggle the switch, does it click or dies it “flop” around?

Comment: It clicks. It works as intended, I just never need it to work. My other option is physically destroying it with pliers, so superglue is better.